# Is it any way to automatically change value of chart after specific period without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I'm using open flash charts in my web but when ' want to update chart's value, I must refresh 
page.
Is it any way to automatically change value of chart after specific period without refreshing page?

Comment: you can use ajax to get updated data and repopulate again your flash charts

Comment: use AJAX for calling new values for chart and refresh that perticular div using Javascript..

Comment: yes,you can use ajax in your application

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same idea in this code . what it does is that it  refreshes the div called livechart and that div holds  the page which queries the database : Good luck

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#livechart").load("autodata.php");
var refeshID = setInterval(function(){
$("#online").load('livechart.php?randval='+ Math.random());
},1000);

});
</script>
```